# Replaceable gun barrel

Tags: weapons, crime

Watching investigative crime shows on TV, I got the idea of criminals developing and using guns with barrels that can be removed and replaced, so that even if the police find the murder weapon on a suspect, they wouldn't be able to match the bullets found in the victim's body to the weapon.

Could this work?

Comment: ??? In many (most?) rifles and revolvers, and in some pistols, the barrel is connected to the receiver with a [threaded interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_threads) and is replaceable. There are even firearms with [quick barrel change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_weapon_system) functionality.

Comment: To whomever closed this, I've asked similar questions about weapons and technology on this site and nobody thought *they* were off topic.

Comment: @kingofpanes, not my close, but I might have voted to close with a few more words thna Monty. What you describe *is already state of the art,* and a very basic thing to people who know anything about guns. In many movies, you will see people clean and disassemble their guns. One of the parts is the barrel. Normally, this barrel is stamped with the serial number of the gun, so letting the barrel disappear will cause just as many questions as letting the gun disappear.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen; While the question looks a lot about the real-world, I highly doubt that the querent is asking whether they can remove their [M24 SWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M24_Sniper_Weapon_System)'s barrel to hide a crime they committed. A much kinder, more reasonable thought would be that they just want to *write* a story in a *fictional world* similar to our own, where such criminals might try such trick. Emphasis on "write" and "fictional world". The querent's knowledge on how the real-world is has no matter on whether this is worldbuilding or not.

Comment: That being said, can you give an estimated time period (19th century, 80s, today....?) you are asking this question? On top of helping your case, it might (or not!) help with determining more accurate answers.

Comment: @o.m. Here’s an idea: you replace the barrel *before* you commit the crime. Fire it. Put the original barrel back in while throwing the used one away. Your gun is perfect, it has the serial number right? Wasn’t you! Seems something a criminal would come up with.

Comment: Eli Witney made this possible in 1798. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchangeable_parts. My only qualm with this question is that it really belongs on engineering.stackexchange.com. The flaw with putting it there is that the would take it as a serious question and might refuse to answer it on those principals.

Comment: Or just run a file through the barrel before you toss the gun.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes.... Sort of**

The problem is not with the concept - almost all Barrels are replaceable - Whether we are talking an LMG Quick-change barrel, an AR-style barrel that can be replaced at home with a few specialist tools or any other firearm.

The reason for this is that a Barrel is a consumable part. That is - Barrels wear out. Depending on Calibre, Ammunition, care etc. an Average Barrel life is around 5,000 rounds. Most shooters aren't going to be firing that amount of Ammunition through a single Firearm, unless they are a competition shooter/Sport shooter or they take their training *very* seriously - a hunter might go through say 100-200 rounds a year on a particular rifle.

Even then, a Worn Barrel unless you are going for precision at longer ranges or you are experiencing excessive blow-by due to increased windage - it's not very common.

So this is the 'Yes' Part - you can replace the Barrel.

The Sort of part is that TV Shows take real life Forensics and Hollywood-ize them - for example - when you see a 'Perfect Match' - Nope, doesn't happen.

But let's for the sake of argument say that in your story/world it does - there's an even easier option:

**Lapping the Barrel**

This is used to clean the Barrel with a very fine grinding paste to remove tool marks from the lands/grooves/bore of the Barrel and to remove any Lead deposits - This process, done aggressively enough would alter the Barrel enough that it's no longer a perfect Match and it's much cheaper.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this. Of course doing so shortly before the weapon is seized for forensic examination would likely cause a competent/experienced  ballistics technician some concern. Said concerns then duly being forwarded to the lead investigators on the case. (Who might then just have a few additional questions for the owner. )

Answer (score 5):

Small imprecisions in the inner shape of a barrel create imprints on the fired bullets which can be interpreted by forensic scientists. Other clues which can be analyzed are imprints of the firing pin on the firing cap, and DNA traces on spent cases. (A revolver would not leave those behind if it is not reloaded at the scene of the crime.)

Present-day handguns can be disassembled into multiple parts, one of them is the barrel. The barrel can **already** be replaced, but the barrel ist a relatively large, relatively expensive part, and stamped with a serial number. So the barrel would not routinely be thrown away. What does that leave?

- There are [frangible bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frangible_bullet), designed for use against soft targets (read, unarmored people) in environmnents like aircraft. However, they might not come apart enough to prevent analysis when they do *not* strike a wall.
- A couple of years ago, a German computer science magazine and a licensed gunsmith collaborated to test the plans for a [3d-printed gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_printed_firearm). (I'm sure there were other tests, I recall reading that one.) Their assessment was that the first couple of shots did jam because the fitting needed asjustment, then a couple of shots worked, then it was worn out and ceased to work reliably. So, not a practical or safe weapon.
  One might come up with a gun design which has a disposable insert *inside* the permanent barrel. Currently such inserts are used to alter the caliber of a weapon, e.g. a single-shot hunting rifle. They are not disposable and the weapon is *normally* used with the regular barrel. The variant would be designed to work *only* with an insert in place, and to feed ammunition from a magazine.

- A more futuristic option might be a [saboted bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabot_(firearms)#Expanding_cup_sabot) with sabots which come apart after firing in a way that prevents analysis. The challenge, here, would be that they must be rugged enough to last during the firing, so they cannot simply burn up. Materials similar ot a frangible bullet?
- One could, obviously, use a shotgun with pellets to avoid bullet rifling. There are shotshells for some common handgun calibers, but they tend to damage a rifled barrel.

Comment: Also should be noted that a large portion of forensic "science" is just a step or so away from being pseudoscience or downright scam-artist quackery. Real life cases of bullets being matched to specific barrels are very rare.

Comment: Here’s an idea: you replace the barrel *before* you commit the crime. Fire it. Put the original barrel back in while throwing the used one away. Your gun is perfect, it has the serial number right? Wasn’t you! Seems something a criminal would come up with.

Comment: Worth mentioning the single-shot Thompson Contender specifically, since it's designed to have different barrels attached to allow firing different calibre rounds.  The "original" barrel/s sold with the frame may (?) have corresponding serial numbers, but an after-market purchase of a longer/different calibre barrel could presumably be done in a relatively untraceable manner in the USA, at least.  Oh, and don't forget MetalStorm, where the concept of reloading is to replace a loaded barrel with a new loaded barrel, rather than round being in a magazine.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055, in the US, why not buy an entire new weapon? I believe that in in Germany barrels are one of the components which legally equal the entire firearm.

Comment: @o.m. similarly in Australia, any part of a firearm is legally considered to be a firearm.  And I agree, if a smart criminal was going to use a firearm in a crime then the best thing to do is use an untraceable firearm and dispose of the entire thing afterwards since, for example, cases can sometimes be matched to marks from the  extractor and/or firing pin indentations on the primer.  However, since the OP is asking only about swapping barrels, throwing in a couple of IMO interesting examples.

Comment: @o.m. deception could be a reason. If they are looking for a .32 acp for example, an uncommon cartridge, they may knock on my door. If I provide my .32 and they determine it is not a match, then I get taken off the suspect list. Buying replacement barrels is easy, and some companies just make custom ones. But you can also bet law enforcement knows this and would have checked financial records to see if I made a purchase from any known sources. Also, many guns like the bond derringers are designed to have the barrels swapped regularly. You can buy those through the mail with no ID.

Comment: Another problem with saboted rounds is that they tend to increase barrel wear.

Answer (score 3):

**Calibre Conversion Sleeve**

What you want is actually something that alters the calibre of the weapon and can be removed easily.

See the [Calibre Conversion Sleeve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliber_conversion_sleeve)

You slip in the converter into a larger calibre weapon and remove it when finished.

Answer (score 1):

As most have already stated, there aren't a wealth of firearms in this modern era that don't have replaceable barrels. Some are harder to remove, but a competent gunsmith could handle those. Most, like a common glock, for example, require no special tools. You can pick up a spare barrel at a gun show in cash and leave no trail back to you.

If you are writing a story and need something like this to throw some detectives off your case, you may instead want to consider the numerous ways a firearm can be purchased legally without any paper trail leading back to you at all. As O.M. pointed out in the comments, why not just have a separate gun? Well, the mob did exactly that all the time. Cheap, single use snubbies that ended up in a river after a murder were practically textbook cliche.

Ok, so where do you get them? Gun shows for one. They are practically a monthly assembly in the southern red states in the USA. Park a few blocks away, use cash, wear a sun hat, and blend in. Wait a while before your mission, and it may be very hard to track this purchase down. All gun show purchases I have made or known about have been completely absent of paperwork.

Armslist.com - they have changed a little as of covid, but back in the day any idiot could post a listing to sell their guns privately. I bought a couple brush hunting guns from people on that site and neither one of them filled out a bill of sale or even looked at my ID. Nowadays you have to pay to post or see listings, but people can get around that by putting their phone numbers in the pictures that you can see for free. So if your story requires someone who MUST acquire a gun without trace, and the type doesn't matter all that much, you can have them hunt the listings there (incognito from an internet cafe) till they find what they need that happens to have a phone number and then they can use a burner phone to text the seller and transact. If they go down the bill of sale road, then your character needs to shelf that gun and look for the next until they encounter someone who forgets to do the paperwork part. It is more common than you might think.

Estate sales. Many people just sell off inherited guns without knowing or caring of the expected protocols. You're supposed to get a bill of sale with the purchaser's info on it, but few do that. If you have ever heard of people reciting the line "close the gunshow loop" - this is what they refer to. The loophole that says any private sales of guns need not go through the background check system. FFL holders have to play by the rules but private parties don't.

Mail order barrels - You can buy barrels online. This will leave a paper trail, but not one in the gun registry. Buy a barrel, swap out your original, commit a crime, swap the original barrel back in the gun, CHANGE AMMUNITION, then go out to the desert and shoot a couple hundred rounds into some cans so you build up a wealth of powder residue that matches the changed ammo, and leave it uncleaned till the cops come a knockin. When you hand over your gun,  those barely adequate comparison tests will have just too much out of place to consider it a match. You may not avoid the suspect list, but you probably won't be taking top billing if played right. That is, till they realize you bought something from Bo and Luke's gun ranch a year ago and their catalog clearly shows barrels for your gun. Then they piece it all together and haul you away because they are detectives and they know of these tactics. Still, could be done this way if you were smart enough about masking every bit of info and internet gateways you use to orchestrate this.

Also, if they use a ghost gun, their top priority after the crimes would be to fully dismantle the pieces and scatter them across as much land as possible in any way that could not result in the pieces being identified. For polymer guns, you can remove all metal parts and simply burn the polymer parts and mix the goop and ashes into a colorful mosaic flower pot. The barrel and the slide might have to be baked into a brick and laid out in a garden wall or tossed into a land fill. Probably many better ways to get rid of the parts, but I'm just throwing out basic ideas here. I've never actually tried to completely dispose of a gun, but I have dismantled them down to every last piece.

So while this doesn't directly respond to your question about barrels, it does explain much easier ways to achieve effectively the same thing. Why don't criminals do this? Because they are unaware of these loopholes, too poor to willy nilly buy guns in secret from websites, or just don't have the brain power to think things through. I mean, until some idiot posts about it on the internet and fills their murderous brains up with info we'd all prefer they don't have... feel free to delete this post if you think it is too much info.

Answer (score 1):

### You’ve just moved the goal posts

Instead of “how do I dispose of this gun”, the problem becomes “how do I dispose of this barrel”?  I’m not sure that this problem is any easier to solve.

Also, virtually all guns have interchangeable barrels (within the make) already.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the barell in situ and throw it away? Difficult.
Reboring a rifle is very usual process. Could be done right after the crime and all traces would be gone.

Best?

Never have the projectile interact with the barrel, beyond the gas-sealing effect. Just put the bullet on two rails, with the gas sealed by a ejectable and burnable sledge-cartridge.
No contact, no traces, just acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

We already have 3D printed guns.  I won't google it to get onto some watch list somewhere, but there is regular murders here with 3D printed guns.  They sort of look like flare guns.  And they still catch them, even when something as simple as a microwave can destroy the printed gun.

So the answer is it works, but you didn't solve the problem.